# Argo CD stuck in deadlock when deleting its installation via Helm with Terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am installing Argo CD in a cluster using a Helm release via Terraform. It installs Argo CD CRDs and automatically add a custom project and a initial application. This application monitors a path with other applications (app of apps).

If I want to remove Argo CD and all its apps and `argocd` namespace from the cluster using `terraform destroy`, it usually gets stuck in a deadlock for deleting the apps.

I understand that having the finalizers below will make the deletion of the app cascde and delete all the resources when using `kubectl delete app ...`, which is good:

```yaml
metadata:
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
```

However, in my app definitions I also have the sync policy for `prune` and `autoHeal` set to `true` so if an app is accidentally deleted, it's recreated immediately like this:

```yaml
syncPolicy:
  automated:
    prune: true
    selfHeal: true
```

Am I right to assume that these two definitions are conflicting and causing the deadlock when destroying Argo CD with Terraform? The `destroy` command tries to delete the app which gets stuck in a loop recreates it everytime.

If that's the case, how can I achieve that Argo CD will recreate an app if it is deleted accidentally (via UI, `kubectl` or `argocd` CLI) but will be completely pruned with `terraform destroy`?